# How to update multiple record at once/one db interaction in mongodb using springboot application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a requirement where i have 100 plus data in mongodb collection ,i need to update each object in the collection but mongoTemplate.findAndModify will update one at a time .So here db interaction will be 100 which is not effective.I need to do update using one db call.Is there any approach.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/63401555/7975771 help you?

Comment: Yaa It's helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object-list (ex: contents) with updated data and use `contentRepository.saveAll(contents);` It will update using one db call.