# Performing update using @Query via Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

i wanted to do a direct update to mongodb and setting `someflag` to either true or false for my use case. To be effecient i do not want to query all documents and set the `someflag` and save it back to db. i just want to directly update it on db just like when doing update on mongodb terminal.

Here is the sample document. NOTE: these documents can number from 1 ~ N so i need to handle efficiently big datas

```
{
  _id: 60db378d0abb980372f06fc1
  someid: 23cad24fc5d0290f7d5274f5
  somedata: some data of mine
  flag: false
}
```

Currently im doing an `@Query` method on my repository

```
@Query(value ="{someid: ?0}, {$set: {flag: false}}")
void updateFlag(String someid)
```

Using the above syntax, it doesnt work, i always get an exception message below;

> Failed to instantiate void using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with
> arguments

How do i perform a direct update effeciently without querying all those document and updating it back to db?

Comment: Do u have default constructor in your class?

Comment: which class? Repository or the Model that relates to this Repository?

Comment: U need to have default constructor in Model class

Comment: ohh i see, which constructor should i have, the one with all the class members as parameters?

Comment: No, you need to have no arguments constructor like in Person class, no argument constructor is  `Person(){}`

Comment: tried using both `@NoArgs..` since i am using Lombok and manually adding no args constructor the same as you commented. i have the same error/exception

Comment: if you have @NoArgsConstrutor in lombok, no issues then

Comment: still got the same exception message after adding `@NoArgsConstructor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the BulkOperations class (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/BulkOperations.html)

Sample codes:
[Spring Data Mongodb Bulk Operation Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964266/spring-data-mongodb-bulk-operation-example)